# Is it possible to display a UI within google spreadsheet but not use the google container bound script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to design a UI for google spreadsheets but currently the options allow for a UI to be displayed as a seperate webpage or within the container bound scripting option. Webapps for other google products like gmail allow for content (html, etc.) to be drawn on/over/within the gmail page (the extension "equire" is a great example).

I would like to design a google sheet UI that functions similarly. Is this possible or am I bound to do UI either in a seperate webpage or inside the container-bound script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a Apps Script library that shows the UI. This script will not be container bound. However, you'll have to call this script's functions from within a container bound script with a shell function in your spreadsheet. Something like

**Apps Script library (not container bound)**

```
function showUI(){
  /* UI code here */
}
```

**In your spreadsheet**

```
function onOpen(){ // or whatever 
  Library.showUI();
}
```

Maybe if you explain why you need to do this, then some other better alternative might arise

Comment: Thanks Sirk, I would use it to enter and manage a product database. When I have several hundred products with 50+ columns, it becomes a scrolling-nightmare to check between different products. Having a simple UI editor would allow me to quickly call a productin that database and edit it, while still being allowed to manually modify the spreadsheet itself as well.